In what tv show do the protagonists hesitantly use a crematorium to dispose of bodies?

Media: Live-action TV series (or film)
Date of release/watch: after 2010 (recently produced)
Scene summary: The protagonist and his son or protege are in a crematorium overseeing the disposal of a body they had something to do with (murder, accidental or otherwise) and the son/protege is disgusted and distraught, so the protagonist is trying to comfort them, saying things like, "This is the last time we have to do this, I promise", and I believe this would be at least the second time they had to resort to visiting the crematorium. They either somehow own the crematorium or bribed the silence of the manager.
Setting: Very similar to Ozark or Breaking Bad, so a crime drama, in which the protagonist gets in over their heads in the criminal world and at one point has to resort to something as horrible as disposing of a body illegally.
Country: USA (English language)

Having searched through keywords like disposal-of-a-body, cremation, etc. on IMDb, I've been unable to find it, so I'm hoping the description rings a bell with someone.

Hmmm. Well Six Feet Under ended in 2005, so I doubt that's it and Good Behavior just finished it's second season and is too recant (the description for some things is off too) and then the only other scenes that comes to mind is an episode or two of Boardwalk Empire, which finsihed it's run in 2010 and is a period piece. The only other thing I can think of is maybe The Sapranos, which I have never seen and it finished in 2007. But probably none of these are it.

@DarthLocke It is possibly a movie, even though I'm more inclined to remember it as a TV show. You are correct in that it is none of those suggestions.

There was something a bit similar in Mr Robot too. And Future man.

@madmada I haven't seen Mr Robot or Future man. I'm wondering if it is Ozark, it's been a while since I saw it. It does fit the premise, since the protagonist owns many businesses as a way to launder money, perhaps one of those is a crematorium.

I think they did actually acquire a funeral home in Ozark (I recall a scene with the wife negotiating with the director over the ludicrous price of arrangements for her real estate agent friend's mother.)  Although I don't recall the scene the OP describes happening thereafter.  Perhaps it did, but with different characters, not father and son?  I don't recall their kids being directly involved in their shenanigans.
